# How to change alpha=0.02 in Proc ANOVA

Tags: sas

In SAS, may i know how to change alpha=0.02 in Proc Anova, as default alpha is 0.05

```
proc anova  data=data1 alpha=0.02;

class cmg ;

model wmg=cmg ;

run;
```

If I give alpha=0.02 after data its not working.

Comment: Alpha doesn't come into play in PROC ANOVA since it reports the p-value and there's no conclusion, that's up to you. Changing Alpha won't change the output you get. Clarify what you're looking for here in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `proc anova` but, from a quick look a the documentation, it seems like the `alpha=` option is available on the `means` statement:

```
proc anova data=data1 alpha=0.02;
class cmg ;
model wmg=cmg ;
means cmg / alpha=0.02;
run;
```

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_anova_sect012.htm